# Adding namespace to enum types in flatbuffer schema

Tags: c++11, flatbuffers

I am working on a tool to convert json schema to flatbuffer schema (.fbs). I have a Json schema which is perfectly valid. While I try to achieve that I am facing the issue of duplicated enumeration. So I'm thinking of adding namespaces to my enums and tables in my fbs. Is this possible?

Comment: `enum class` might also be a solution. Can you show a [mcve] of code that has this issue?

Comment: I presume you're asking about adding namespaces to the generated schema? Yes you can, see the Flatbuffers documentation.